# Create calendar to post overseas

Tags: photos.app

I would like to create a calendar from my iPhotos and mail it directly in a country different from my billing country (to reduce delivery cost). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. You'll have to create a contact while setting up the Create a calendar process. You can add an address and ship it to that location.

If you can't locate it, call Apple Support and they can assist you very easily with a screenshare.

Answer (score 2):

I don‘t think you can do this with iPhoto/Photos. But in most countries there are local offerings with either a web interface or even an application to create calendars and have them printed. Either ask your local friends or (it it should be a surprise) use the search engine of your choice to search for offerings.